# Counting monotonically increasing sequence that $a(i) < i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

How many sequences $(a(1),\dots,a(n))$ of integers are there such that $0 \leq a(1) \leq a(2)\le \dots \leq a(n)$
and $a(i) < i$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$?

My guess is it's related to Catalan numbers.

Comment: Do you have a guess? If you compute the numbers of such sequences for $n=1,2,3,4$, you will see a famous sequence emerge, which should give you some ideas for how to proceed.

Comment: @MikeEarnest so i think i understand now , for my question of f(x)>=x there it would be catalan numbers too right ? From the graph made below , we can conclude the answer will be same for both cases of f(x) >= x or f(x) <= x right ?

Comment: But also i think in my case the condition should be f(x) > x or f(x)<x as then only catalan will appear as such what is done here isnt ? @MikeEarnest Sir  the = condition gives many more possible ways right Sir ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

The Catalan numbers enumerate the set of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$, where each step is one unit up or right, and which stay below the line $y=x$. Try to find a bijection between such paths and the sequences you are counting. The conditions "$a(i)<i$" and "the path must be below the line $y=x$" are strikingly similar$\dots$

**Further hint**

When $n=2$, there are two possible lattice paths:

```
   |      _|
_ _|    _|
```

and there are two possible sequences:

$$
(0,0) \qquad and\qquad (0,1)
$$

Notice that the path on the left stays pretty low to the ground (until the very end), while the path on the right is gradually increasing. Similarly, the sequence $(0,0)$ stays low, while $(0,1)$ gradually increases.

When $n=3$, there are $5$ paths:

```
     |       |     _|       |       _|
     |      _|    |      _ _|     _|
_ _ _|  _ _|   _ _|    _|       _|
```

sorted in terms of how quickly they increase. Similarly, there are $5$ sequences:

$$
(0,0,0)\quad (0,0,1)\quad(0,0,2)\quad(0,1,1)\quad(0,1,2)
$$
Try to see show the general trend of the paths corresponds to the general trend of the sequences, and use that to construct a bijection that works for any $n$.

**Solution**

We prove this using a bijection. Given a monotonic sequence $(a(1),\dots,a(n))$ with $a(i)<i$, we will product a unique lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ which stays at or below the line $y=x$, such that all lattice paths are generated. Since it is well-known that the number of such lattice paths is $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$, this proves that there are $C_n$ monotonic sequences with $a(i)<i$.

Specifically, given $(a(1),\dots,a(n))$, let $P$ be the lattice path such that, for each fixed $x\in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, the maximum value of $y$ such that $(x,y)$ is a point on $P$ is $a(x)+1$. This uniquely defines $P$.

Comment: but how can you transform the sequence 0,0,0,0,0 to a path from (0,0) to (5,5) @Mike Earnest

Comment: @T.fizuty See the edited question for further hints. I do not want to give you the answer, because I think you will enjoy discovering it for yourself!

Comment: @MikeEarnest hello, could you please help me with explaining clearly for the bijection. I am going to have an email next 2 days :( This exercise is quite important to me. Thank you